# Start Activity From Seprate Java Class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to start Activity from seprate java class but it fails.
 I dont Know what is the error in this code.
I also catch the Exception [Here is the Exception I catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvNk.png). I also fails to understand this Exception.

```
public class ConnectorForLocateIndividual{
String id;
Context c;
public ConnectorForLocateIndividual(){}
public ConnectorForLocateIndividual(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public ConnectorForLocateIndividual(Context context){
    c = context;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void startAc(){
    try {
        Intent i = new Intent(c, sign_in.class);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c , e.getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: unwanted constructors just like unwanted taxes , `Activities` has their own context

Comment: What u mean bro ??

Comment: `Activities` has their own `context` so `c.startActivity(i);` should be `startActivity(i);` , no need create constructors

Comment: I know bro but it is a seprate java class which extends Activity.. I just write "extends Activity" for testing purpose but it not works

Comment: i will answer this but i need more info...1. I need the code for sign_in.class - it has to be an activity. 2. Also, will ConnectorForLocateIndividual be extended by other activities? because I dont see any activity life cycle methods. 3. both activities must be in the android manifest - are they?

Comment: I have an ActivityA and sign_in Activity  And i also have a java class which is ConnectorForLocateIndividual.  I send a Context of ActivityA to ConnectorForLocateIndividual by constructor. And Start sign_in Activity in this Seprate Class by calling method `startAc()` .
1.sign_in is an Activity
2.ConnectorForLocateIndividual do not extends any activity
3. Both Activities ActivityA and sign_in are in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are on initializing Context c in ConnectorForLocateIndividual class. that's why you are getting null pointer when trying to use it. Make sure you use:

```
public ConnectorForLocateIndividual(Context context){
c = context;
}
```

this particular constructor while creating a new object of ConnectorForLocateIndividual class.